# XSLT to change namespace

Tags: xml, xslt

**I have this XML code:**

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="something2" xmlns:oas="something1" xmlns:bill="something">
    <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="something_else">
     <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>SYSUSER</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="PasswordText">sysuser00</wsse:Password>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
   <GetBillList xmlns="old_uri" xmlns:xsi="else" xsi:schemaLocation="old_schema">
   <Case>
   <CaseID>699677</CaseID> 
   <BillGroup casref="123">
   <BillGroupID>1</BillGroupID> 
   </BillGroup>
   </Case>
   <StartDate>2014-06-12</StartDate> 
   </GetBillList>
   </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to change `old_uri` & `old_schema` into `new_uri` & `new_schema` respectively, along with attribute conversion into element of `BillGroup` node.

**XSLT used:**

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:bill="something">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="bill:BillGroup">
   <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Target XML:**

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="something2" xmlns:oas="something1" xmlns:bill="something">
    <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="something_else">
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>SYSUSER</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="PasswordText">sysuser00</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <GetBillList xmlns="new_uri" xmlns:xsi="else" xsi:schemaLocation="new_schema">
        <Case>
            <CaseID>699677</CaseID>
            <BillGroup>
                <casref>123</casref>
                <BillGroupID>1</BillGroupID>
            </BillGroup>
        </Case>
        <StartDate>2014-06-12</StartDate>
       </GetBillList>
        </soapenv:Body>
     </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: It looks like you accidentally pasted your source XML twice instead of pasting your XSLT attempt.  Could you update your question?

Comment: I am so sorry. Edited the code now. When I pass original URL in xmlns:bill,  caseref is getting converted into element. Just want to change namespaces. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your input XML, your `billGroup` element is part of the `old_uri` namespace, not the `something` namespace. This means you need to adjust your namespace prefixes accordingly. You also need to change it to match the attribute of `billGroup` if you want to change the attribute into an element:

```
<xsl:template match="old:BillGroup/@*">
   <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="new_uri">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Here `old` is a prefix that is bound to the uri `old_uri`.

To change the namespace uri from `old_uri` to `new_uri` you can have a template that matches elements in the old namespace

```
<xsl:template match="old:*">
   <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="new_uri">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

And to change the schema location, have a template that matches the attribute

```
<xsl:template match="@xsi:schemaLocation">
   <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:text>new_schema</xsl:text>
   </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="else" xmlns:old="old_uri" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@xsi:schemaLocation">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
    <xsl:text>new_schema</xsl:text>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="old:*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="new_uri">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="old:BillGroup/@*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="new_uri">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Your code is working properly. Only thing is that schema location is not getting changed. :(

Comment: I made a small change & now its working fine.. Thanks a lot for your help.